# try to create a SOAP client but I get nothing when i call the server

Tags: php, xml, soap, soap-client

xI try to create a SOAP client and use the following code but i got nothing when i call the server, what should i do to run the requist and get the results,

```
<?php
require_once "lib/nusoap.php";
$client = new nusoap_client("http://test.gsisservices.com:7010/GServices/WSHOT-PS?wsdl",  true);

$pramas = array("Version" => "1",
                "AvailRequestSegments" => array(
                    "AvailRequestSegment" => array(
                        "StayDateRange" => array("Start" => "2015-10-20", "End" => "2015-10-25"),
                        "RoomStayCandidates" => array(
                            "RoomStayCandidate" => array(
                                "GuestCounts" => array("GuestCount" => array("Count" => "1", "Age" => "30")),
                                "GuestCounts" => array("GuestCount" => array("Count" => "1", "Age" => "12")))),
                        "HotelSearchCriteria" => array(
                            "Criterion" => array(
                                "HotelRef" => array("SegmentCategoryCode" => "3"))),
                        "TPA_Extensions" => array(
                            "Providers" => array(
                                "Provider" = array("Provider" => "GSI", 
                                    "Credentials" => array(
                                        "CredentialCode" => array("CredentialCode" => "xxxxxxxxx", "CredentialName" => "AccountCode"),
                                        "CredentialCode" => array("CredentialCode" => "xxxxxxxxx", "CredentialName" => "Password"),
                                        "CredentialCode" => array("CredentialCode" => "", "CredentialName" => "System"),
                                        "CredentialCode" => array("CredentialCode" => "", "CredentialName" => "SalesChannel"),
                                        "CredentialCode" => array("CredentialCode" => "", "CredentialName" => "Language"),
                                        "CredentialCode" => array("CredentialCode" => "", "CredentialName" => "ConnectionString")
                                    ), 
                                    "ProviderAreas" => array(
                                        "Area" => array("TypeCode" => "Country", "AreaCode" => "ES"),
                                        "Area" => array("TypeCode" => "Province", "AreaCode" => "ES011")
                                        )
                                )
                            ),
                            "ProviderTokens" => array(
                                "Token" => array("TokenName" => "ResponseMode", "TokenCode" => "4")
                            )
                        )
                    )
                );
$hotel = $client->call("OTA_HotelAvail", $pramas);

$error = $client->getError();
if ($error) {
    echo "<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>" . $error . "</pre>";
}

if ($client->fault) {
    echo "<h2>Fault</h2><pre>";
    print_r($hotel);
    echo "</pre>";
}else {
    $error = $client->getError();
    if ($error) {
        echo "<h2>Error</h2><pre>" . $error . "</pre>";
    }
    else {
       var_dump($hotel); 

    }
}
echo "sss";
?>
```

I try to create a SOAP client and use the following code but i got nothing when i call the server, what should i do to run the requist and get the results,

Comment: Check your error logs.

Comment: Update :
i have fix the syntax errors and now i got this error 
-

Constructor error

wsdl error: Getting http://test.gsisservices.com:7010/GServices/WSHOT-PS?wsdl - HTTP ERROR: Couldn't open socket connection to server http://test.gsisservices.com:7010/GServices/WSHOT-PS?wsdl, Error (110): Connection timed out

Error

wsdl error: Getting http://test.gsisservices.com:7010/GServices/WSHOT-PS?wsdl - HTTP ERROR: Couldn't open socket connection to server http://test.gsisservices.com:7010/GServices/WSHOT-PS?wsdl, Error (110): Connection timed out